# Checking if a word is equal to a specific word in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a method which will search through an ArrayList containing several words searching for a specific String. Where if the String is not equal to any words in the ArrayList it will add the word to the list, and if the word already exists in the list, it will count how many times the word occurs and then add one more, which will represent the last String input. 
This is what I've got so far in my code:

```
public void leggTilOrd(String ord) {
    if (Ord.contains(ord)) {
        teller++;
    }

    if (!Ord.contains(ord)) {
        Ord.add(ord);
    }

    System.out.println(teller);
}
```

Obviously this will only add one more number in the counter (teller), so what I'm trying to achieve it to add 1 on top of all the occurrences of that specific String in the list and this is where I'm stuck.

Edit: I should also mention that Ord is an ArrayList I've created earlier in the code.
Here's the full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ordliste {

private ArrayList<String> Ord = new ArrayList<String>();
private int teller = 0;


public void lesBok (String filnavn) throws Exception{
Scanner fil = new Scanner(new File(filnavn));
while(fil.hasNextLine()){
  Ord.add(fil.next());
} fil.close();
}

 public void leggTilOrd(String ord){
 if(Ord.contains(ord)){
  teller++;
  } if (!Ord.contains(ord)){
  Ord.add(ord);
  } System.out.println(teller);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `add 1 on top of all the occurrences of that specific String`? You want add word to list or just increment counter?

Comment: A bit confused what you're trying to do. Could you rephrase/clarify your question?

Comment: Example of list, and results for specific cases would help understand what you want to achieve. For now I suspect that you may simply want to remove second `if` and execute `Ord.add(ord);` unconditionally

Answer (score 3):

Are you tied to using an `ArrayList`? I'd recommend using a `Map<String, Integer>` instead and store the number of occurrences of a specific string as value in the map:

```
if (map.get(ord) != null) {
  map.put(ord, map.get(ord) + 1);
}
else {
  map.put(ord, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing this , you can keep track of the strings in your list using a Set

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

public void leggTilOrd(String ord) {
    if (set.contains(ord) != null) {
        teller++;
    } else {
        Ord.add(ord);
        set.add(ord);
    }

    System.out.println(teller);
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using a map, if you're just mapping the key to itself, and the only thing you're using it for is to check whether the map already contains the key? You seem to be using the map in exactly the same way that the OP is using their list...

Comment: access time of map is constant

Comment: Then do you maybe want to use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead? That has constant lookup time as well, with the added benefit of being a `Collection` (which `Map` is not).

Comment: I agree , but set will have problem if you want to track duplicates , in map you only need to change the value to Integer and track the number of occurences

Comment: Sure, but that's not how you're using it here. Mapping the value to itself is just wasted memory, and somewhat of a misuse of the map interface. As is, your map isn't tracking duplicates so you're trying to use it as a set.

Comment: you are absolutely right, guess i will edit my answer then

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, do you increment `teller` each time you add a different word?

This is a simple way to do what I believe you are attempting, and should get you going in the right direction.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class test
{
  static int teller = 0;

  static List<String> words = Arrays.asList("dog", "cat", "dog");

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(teller);
    addAndCount("dog");
    System.out.println(teller);
    teller = 0;
    addAndCount("cat");
    System.out.println(teller);
    teller = 0;
    addAndCount("fish");
    System.out.println(teller);
  }

  public static void addAndCount(String newWord)
  {
    teller += 1 + Math.toIntExact(
        words.stream().filter(string -> newWord.equals(string)).count());
    words.add(newWord);
  }
}
```